# How can i prevent content to not exceed the length of container?

Tags: css, height, width, containers

I am showing a list of clients on a page and on the right side i have a calendar showing to schedule a new date for appoinment.  When testing the output i found that if there are lot of clients coming on that day, the list exceeds the length of the container.  What to do about this..

some code:

container:

```
#container {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin:0 auto; 
min-height: 600px;
width: 900px;
border:0px solid #999999;
margin-top:30px;
font-size:15px;
color: #000000;
margin-bottom:60px;
position:absolute;
}

#calendar {
margin-left:400px;
}
```

Comment: Could you show your code using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Can you post the html? Edit: +1 above ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want #container to expand at all?

If not, change min-height to height, and add overflow:hidden;

An even better solution would be to modify whatever is supplying the data so that you only receive a pre-determined number of clients at any given time.

Comment: It didn't work.  It only expanded the height of the container by 0.5 inch.

Comment: yes i want the #container to expand to the length of the list if it exceeds the length of the #container.

Comment: I can haz code? I'm sure that we will be able to help you if you could show us exactly what it is that you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Use min-height.  Example:

```
min-height: 300px;
```

If you specify this style, the element will be 300px high, or tall enough to contain its contents - whichever is higher.

(Note that not all web browsers work with min-height.)

Comment: I am using min-height in the code i posted above. i am on firefox.

Comment: thanks i think the problem is with the position:absolute in the #container.  i forgot to copy that into the xample.  if i remove that then the height adjusts but then the calendar goes all the way down.

Answer (score 0):

Is `overflow: auto;` what you're looking for? If the content exceeds the size of the container, it adds scroll bars.

Comment: No, i am saying that the container contains the list of these clients... but the list is exceeding the length of the container, so its going out of it.  how can i do it so that the height of the container adapts to the lenght of the list..

Comment: If you remove any height properties from the container, and it isn't in a fixed layout or anything, the containter *should* automatically expand

Comment: do you have a demo or example where we can see it?